# Как передать коллекцию java в macros freemarker'а?

Tags: java, freemarker

Использую spring-boot и шаблонизатор freemarker. Я хочу сделать одну основную страницу и собрать ее из макросов. Вот основная страница в итоге она должна состоять из подключенных макросов:

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>
<#import "parts/edmcTable.ftl" as et>
<#include "parts/functions.ftl">

<@c.main>
    <@ et.edmc/>
</@c.main>
```

В файле, в котором я определяю макрос(`edmcTable.ftl`) мне нужно использовать список объектов, который я помещаю в модель спринга в контроллере:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private final ServiceEdmc serviceEdmc;
    private final ServicePortalSol servicePortalSol;

    public MainController(ServiceEdmc serviceEdmc, ServicePortalSol servicePortalSol) {
        this.serviceEdmc = serviceEdmc;
        this.servicePortalSol = servicePortalSol;
    }

    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public String getDataAllOrders(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("ordersEdmc", serviceEdmc.findAllOrders());
        model.addAttribute("ordersPortalSol", servicePortalSol.findAllOrders());
        return "main";
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит макрос, который находится в `edmcTable.ftl`:

```
<#macro edmc ordersEdmc>
    <table>
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</#macro>
```

Как можно получить и использовать коллекцию в макросе?

Comment: Вроде так же как везде. Надо только передать её в макрос через параметр. `<@et.edmc ordersEdmc=ordersEdmc/>`

Comment: Столкнулся с тем же вопросом. Скажите пожалуйста, Вам удалось это как-то решить? Спасибо. Помогла официальная документация:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_namespace.html